# Don't want to submit form elements that I hide by hiding parent li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form inputs placed in li element, and am hiding some of them by clicking a button. They get submitted even though they are hidden, so I was wondering what the alternative way would be to hide these element in a way that they will not be submitted?

Comment: Can you post the html? I'm more curious as to why they are getting submitted in the first place. Do you have forms within forms? Something doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will help you, but when you hide can you also disable all the elements in that li, if you are using some JS tool kit(jQuery/prototype etc) you can do it easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide them still, but disable the inputs as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you hide the element, also set the hidden input's attribute disabled to disabled, so it will be excluded during form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Add `disabled="true"` for the elements you are hiding and do not want to send in the form.

Comment: Can you please add some documentation to your answer? Can you separate and format differently your code and explanation?